# How can I do a subquery inside a subquery in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, select

I need to add a subquery to a working function. Instead of `select * from table`, I'd like to `select * from (select * from table where height>1500) as sub`, something that works in other functions I have.

However, it doesn't work in this function. See below:

This works as expected:

```
select row_to_json(t) from (
    select * from table
    where st_intersects(
        st_transform(
            st_setsrid( 
                ST_geomfromgeojson(
                    '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[42.56236553192139,37.96026293121387],[42.56258010864258,37.960165652451245],[42.56299    85332489,37.95957774762163],[42.56308972835541,37.95940856550367],[42.5631058216095,37.95926898996297],[42.56291270256042    5,37.959137873304314],[42.56252110004425,37.9590532817874],[42.561931014060974,37.9590828888294],[42.561678886413574,37.9    59137873304314],[42.56154477596283,37.95921823515514],[42.56145358085632,37.959319744735744],[42.561437487602234,37.95942    548373303],[42.56181299686431,37.959861126796085],[42.562150955200195,37.9601318163297],[42.56202757358551,37.96030522628    786],[42.56236553192139,37.96026293121387]]]}'
                ), 
            4326), 
        3857), 
    table.geom)) 
as t;
```

This doesn't work (added subquery), and I get the error `missing FROM-clause entry for table`:

```
select row_to_json(t) from (
    select * from (
        select * from table where height>1500
    ) sub 
    where st_intersects(
        st_transform(
            st_setsrid( 
                ST_geomfromgeojson(
                    '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[42.56236553192139,37.96026293121387],[42.56258010864258,37.960165652451245],[42.56299    85332489,37.95957774762163],[42.56308972835541,37.95940856550367],[42.5631058216095,37.95926898996297],[42.56291270256042    5,37.959137873304314],[42.56252110004425,37.9590532817874],[42.561931014060974,37.9590828888294],[42.561678886413574,37.9    59137873304314],[42.56154477596283,37.95921823515514],[42.56145358085632,37.959319744735744],[42.561437487602234,37.95942    548373303],[42.56181299686431,37.959861126796085],[42.562150955200195,37.9601318163297],[42.56202757358551,37.96030522628    786],[42.56236553192139,37.96026293121387]]]}'
                ), 
            4326), 
        3857), 
    table.geom)) // <- error points to here
as t;
```

How can I do this? I need to add the string `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE height>1500) AS sub` every time, as this is set somewhere else and needs to be included wholly.

Comment: It might help to paste the text of the error message into your question.  Have you tried adding that as a wrapper to your initial query instead of as a subquery?  Since you are including all fields anyway, it would essentially accomplish the same thing.  From a performance standpoint, it might make sense to limit the number of fields that are being queried each time.

Comment: How can I do that exactly?

Comment: Which part are you asking about?  Error message is a matter of copying from message window if using PGAdmin III into your question.  The rest of it is sort of moot since you solved your issue, unless you want to limit the fields you are returning.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RhodiumToad on #postgres, trick is to use `sub.geom` instead of `table`.

```
 select row_to_json(t) from (
    select * from (
        select * from table where height>1500
    ) as sub 
    where st_intersects(
        st_transform(
            st_setsrid( 
                ST_geomfromgeojson(
                    '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[42.56236553192139,37.96026293121387],[42.56258010864258,37.960165652451245],[42.56299         85332489,37.95957774762163],[42.56308972835541,37.95940856550367],[42.5631058216095,37.95926898996297],[42.5629127025     6042    5,37.959137873304314],[42.56252110004425,37.9590532817874],[42.561931014060974,37.9590828888294],[42.561678886413     574,37.9    59137873304314],[42.56154477596283,37.95921823515514],[42.56145358085632,37.959319744735744],[42.561437487602     234,37.95942    548373303],[42.56181299686431,37.959861126796085],[42.562150955200195,37.9601318163297],[42.5620275735855     1,37.96030522628    786],[42.56236553192139,37.96026293121387]]]}'
                ), 
            4326), 
        3857), 
    sub.geom)) // <-- sub instead of table
 as t;
```